# Pull ONLY Most Recent CallSwitch Info

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

2 Tables one with the generic info, the other showing our phone switch information.  I want to pull the most recent information based off our call switch.  This is sample data for my table structure, how can I ONLY pull the most recent info, even though the callswitch table could possibly contain multiple records for the same day?

Table Structure:

```
   Create Table #PhoneSwitch
    (
      PSID int,
      UserID int,
      #Dialed varchar(100),
      LengthofCall int,
      CallDateTime datetime,
      CallOutcome varchar(100)
    )
    Create Table #ResourceTable
    (
      RID int,
      UserID int,
      AddressMain varchar(100),
      PhoneNameFirst varchar(100),
      PhoneNameLast varchar(100),
      PhoneNameCity varchar(100),
      PhoneNameState varchar(100),
      PhoneNameZip varchar(100)
    )

Insert Into #PhoneSwitch Values 
('1', '311', '5555555555', '0',     '03/16/2015', 'No Connect'), 
('2', '311', '5555555555', '0', '03/16/2015', 'No Connect'),
('3', '311', '5555555555', '0', '03/16/2015', 'No Connect'), 
('4', '511',   '5555555555', '0', '03/15/2015', 'No Connect'), 
('5', '511', '5555555555', '0', '03/15/2015', 'No Connect')

Insert Into #ResourceTable Values 
('1','311','123 Nowhere Street', 'Z',   'F', 'Montreal', 'CA', '123'),
('2','311','123 Nowhere Street', 'Z', 'F', 'Montreal','CA',  '123'),  
('3','311','123 Nowhere Street', 'Z', 'F', 'Montreal', 'CA', '123'),
('4','511','623 Nowhere Street', 'A', 'X', 'Montreal', 'CA', '192'), 
('5','511','623 Nowhere Street', 'A', 'X', 'Montreal', 'CA', '192')
```

And this is the query I tried, but it is not returning ONLY the most recent information from the switch

```
Select case 
         when [UserID] LIKE '311' Then 'Sam Smith' 
         when [UserID] Like '511' Then 'Ricky Zefry' 
       end As [User Name], 
       MAX(PS.CallDateTime) As [Call   Date], 
       RT.AddressMain, RT.PhoneNameFirst, RT.PhoneNameLast, 
       RT.PhoneNameCity,   RT.PhoneNameState, RT.PhoneNameZip
FROM #ResourceTable RT
Inner Join #PhoneSwitch ps
On RT.UserID = PS.UserID
```

EDIT --- I need to show most recent call for both userids!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the top record per `UserID`. Then select this record in an outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   Select case when RT.[UserID] LIKE '311' Then 'Sam Smith' 
               when RT.[UserID] Like '511' Then 'Ricky Zefry' 
          end As [User Name],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  RT.[UserID] ORDER BY PS.CallDateTime DESC) AS rn,
          PS.CallDateTime As [Call   Date], 
          RT.AddressMain, RT.PhoneNameFirst, RT.PhoneNameLast, RT.PhoneNameCity,   
          RT.PhoneNameState, RT.PhoneNameZip
   FROM #ResourceTable RT
   Inner Join #PhoneSwitch ps On RT.UserID = PS.UserID ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/037e5/1)